# Outlook 2016 (and Word) are showing visible newlines; how to hide them?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-office-2016

I;ve just started work at a new firm where for the first time I'm using an Office newer than 2003.  From the point my account was created and I logged in first time, I've been having this problem.

I have tried Show/Hide Editing Marks (ctrl-*) an Show/Hide ¶ (also ctrl-*!!).

Both these options successfully toggle the visibility of tabs (shown as a rightwards grey arrow) and spaces (a mid-height grey dot).  However neither affects the visibility of an arrow at the end of every paragraph, which is displayed as an arrow going down then to the left.  These are visible in the window to compose new emails.  How do I hide them?

Word seems to have the same issue.

Here is the email edit window with Show/Hide Editing Marks activated (note tab and space are visible, as is newline; vertical line is the cursor):

[image]

And here it is with it turned off (note tab and space now hidden, though newline still visible):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the threads below to see if it would be helpful.

[Turn formatting marks on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-formatting-marks-on-or-off-b166e811-d762-4f24-8328-d897cdace459)

[Remove the paragraph symbol from my email text box](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a20cfe80-7611-4c4b-b5c9-216fa06ac8c0/remove-the-paragraph-symbol-from-my-email-text-box?forum=outlook)

Comment: Appreciated but no.  Note the carriage return glyph I cannot get rid of is not on that page, and the buttons/commands mentioned in the article are also mentioned in my question as tried and failed.